# Any way to restore OS after accidental apt removal all package

Tags: 16.04, apt, restore

My younger brother accidentally ran:

```
apt-get install libtool autoconf libexpat1-
```

while installing calf studio gear. Apparently `apt` removes packages if you add a hyphen at end. Now my OS would not even boot.

Is there any way I can restore my system to previous state? Because I had openstack installed and configured on the machine via `conjure-up novalxd`.

Comment: First of all try to boot from a live disk and get a chroot. If this works, we can try to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a backup from before the error, restoring that backup should at least give you a system that boots.  Of course, you'll need to boot your system from Live media or into another installed OS to restore your backup.

If you don't have a (reasonably recent) backup of your OS partition, the fastest way to fix this is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Did not have backup. So reinstalled ubuntu. Could not find any other way.

Comment: If that has solved the situation for you, you can accept my answer (by clicking the checkmark to the left of my answer text).